# JavaScript AJAX library to consume WS REST through JSONP

Tags: javascript, ajax, web-services, rest, jsonp

I'm looking for a lightweight JavaScript AJAX library to consume WS REST through JSONP.

[JX](http://www.openjs.com/scripts/jx/) sounds a good choice but I'm unable to consume a WS REST.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

[Simple, plain AJAX without any Javascript Library](http://blogs.digitss.com/javascript/simple-plain-ajax-without-any-javascript-library/)

Answer (score 0):

[JQuery](http://www.jquery.com) is good - plenty of documentation etc.

Comment: The only functionality that I'm interested in the library is AJAX requests, so I'm targeting for a more lightweight library.